# Would you consider this a security concern? Trying to script cifs

Tags: mount, sudo, root

I’m trying to script mounting a cifs share. Below is my script, which i run on a proxmox v7 debian 11 VM, cli only, no gui. I connect via putty and this script is sitting in `/srv/share`. I also have fstab set up to mount this automatically, but i umount it when testing this script.

```
// Beginning of script  
#! /bin/bash  
share="/storage"

// Test for share connectivity and connect if needed  
if [ ! -d $share/_Scripts ];  
then  
// following command is all one line  
mount -t cifs //x.x.x.x/storage /storage -o uid=root,gid=smb_admins,credentials=/home/xxxxx/.cifs,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770  
else  
echo “Share is already connected”  
fi  
// End of Script
```

If I run this as just my user, it gives no prompt, no errors, nothing. If I then type exit at the command prompt, it outputs “exit” and then “Share is already connected” and drops me back to my user’s command prompt.
However, if I run the script as `sudo`, it asks for my user password, as normal, shows no output, and drops me directly into a root prompt without asking for root’s password, which concerns me somewhat. If I then type `exit` at the root prompt, it does the same thing as under my regular user and drops me back to my regular user’s prompt.

I’m sure its something I’ve screwed up, but that seems like very dangerous behavior to me. Your thoughts?

Comment: One of the design features of `sudo` is that the root password is not needed by users. If you are expecting to have to enter root's password then your system is misconfigured. Also, there is no space between `#!` and `/bin/bash`.

Comment: It's allowed to have a space there, I even once heard someone argue that with a space there the first 32 bits of every file with a shebang are the same. I can't see what that would do, but the point is that the OP's space is not an error.

Comment: `//` is not a comment marker. Please post a version of your script that actually matches reality. Select the block of code and use `{}` to indent it by four spaces. If you want a security review then what we see must match reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is wrong. Supposed to be `#!`, not `$!`. The former is a comment to your shell but tells your operating system which program you want to execute the script with, the latter contains the number of the last executed background job, if I remember correctly. Assuming there's no such thing, it would expand to nothing, so the start of your script just starts a bash process, which you end with exit, after which your actual script runs.

I don't see the security problem, this is a bug in your script, for sure, but whoever executed it had sudo privileges, anyways.

Comment: I checked my script and it was correct.  Not sure how I switched it around.  I was only concerned about this because something is causing it to drop to a full root prompt.  I did try running the script on another VM, and it does the same with needing to type 'exit' after the script has run before it'll print the last echo statement.  But it drops me back to the regular user's prompt as you'd expect.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Now I really don't trust your question any more. Are the "`" around the Mount-line really there?  Please really make sure you've copied & pasted your actual script and not something else.

Comment: No they aren't there in the actual script.  They are there to help format the code in the post, but I've obviously did something wrong.  When I cut and pasted from the script, it formatted it all on one line, so I was trying to get it to view correctly.

Comment: I see what I've done.  I posted this on three different forums.  One of which required the weird formatting, which I must've copied from there to here...  Also should point out  that this issue is occurring on my web facing nextcloud server, which is why I'm concerned.  I dont see any indication of intrusion, but...

Comment: You're first assumption was the correct one.  I had indeed used the wrong she bang.  A non-coder trying to code too late at night, I suppose.  Thanks for you help.

Comment: Happy to help! In that case, accepting the answer to mark this question as solved would be the appropriate thing; otherwise, it might attract other people investing time in answers :)